# Trouble: Firebase: No Firebase App '[DEFAULT]' has been created - call Firebase App.initializeApp() (app-compat/no-app)

Tags: reactjs, firebase

I'm practicing making some projects which are using ReactJS, but when I saved the config file as below, It showed the error as the title. Has anyone ever been trouble with this? Please help me!
Thanks!

```
import { initializeApp } from "firebase/app";
import { getAnalytics } from "firebase/analytics";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import 'firebase/analytics';
import 'firebase/compat/auth';
import 'firebase/compat/firestore';

// TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
// https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries

// Your web app's Firebase configuration
// For Firebase JS SDK v7.20.0 and later, measurementId is optional
const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyD0rxJTIV4RIKfdFJB6G--9md2-SAEDwjs",
  authDomain: "chat-app-d3f09.firebaseapp.com",
  projectId: "chat-app-d3f09",
  storageBucket: "chat-app-d3f09.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "361125159681",
  appId: "1:361125159681:web:9557ff40c4e38e30ba3100",
  measurementId: "G-X1Q63CL2N2"
};

// Initialize Firebase
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();

export { db, auth }
export default firebase
```

Answer (score 3):

You are using firebase version 9 with 8 & >.

Try:

```js
const app = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

//const auth = firebase.auth();
const auth = getAuth(app)
//const db = firebase.firestore();
const db = getFirestore(app)
```

Or if you want to use version 8 & > then:

```js
const app = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
//const analytics = getAnalytics(app);

const auth = firebase.auth();
const db = firebase.firestore();
```

> Note that firebase version 9+ is written in functional way.

Comment: hey hey thank you so much! It worked for me, but I can't vote up for you haha have no idea

Comment: @DennisNguyen Bellow votes you have bird icon to accept answear as correct.